# Resize image using only html and css

Tags: html, css, image, edit

I have an image with height 173px and width 157px .I want to set its height and width to 100 px but when i do so it get streched.I want to use img tag to do this.I have no problem if it is cropped in resizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's stretched. How do you want to do without stretching ?

The only thing you can do is to recreate an image using a server api and do not use the resize in css.

But, it will strecht because you do not kept the ratio between width and height !

Answer (score 4):

Give `height:auto` when you change it's width. Write like this:

```
img{
 width:100px;
height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it gets stretched when you apply a different multiplication factor in the horizontal direction than in the vertical. You may want to try `width:auto` or `heigth:auto`.

Edit: or if you don't have a problem with cropping the image, you can put it in a container element (for instance a div), on which you set `overflow:hidden`.

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden">
 <img src="your image" alt="" style="width:100px; height:auto" />
</div>
```

Another edit:
Just realised it's possible to crop it using only CSS on the image (and not needing a parent container), by using the `clip` property. See [W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#clipping).
However, sadly enough that requires the element to be absolutely positioned, so unless you know exactly where in the window you want to put it, you'll have to put it in a parent container anyway. Oh well.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe it can be accomplished with the `img`-tag, as it will stretch the image according to your provided width/height. It would however be possible to use a `div`-element instead, and assign the image as a background. That way the image will not be re-sized, the parts of the image not possible of to display within your 100x100 px element will appear "cropped".

```
.image-element
{
   background-image: url('yourimage.png');
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

By using the `background-position` attribute you could also control which parts of the image that gets "cropped".